# How to determine if it is a kinetic, energy or power weapon?

Tags: destiny-2

I'm about to choose between 3 different exotic weapons as quest reward.

For me it is very important which of them belongs to what slot, as that is highly dependable for my decision. But I can't figure out what the type of the weapon is from the quest reward dialog or item inspection.

Am I missing something? Or might there be a way to figure it out?

Comment: Just so you know, all weapons you get as a reward (and armors you got from aprevious quest) are all random drops as well. If you didn't pick it now you can always get them later.

Answer (score 11):

**Kinetic weapons** have their Power value in white, with **no elemental symbol** (red flame, blue spark, purple vortex) by the value.

**Energy weapons** and **Power weapons** both have elemental damage. Those are the symbols I mentioned above and correspond to Solar, Arc, and Void.

Exotics notwithstanding (though I believe only Fighting Lion breaks the mold by being a Grenade Launcher in your Energy Weapon slot),

Kinetic weapons and Energy weapons share the same weapon type. These are:

> Auto Rifles, Pulse Rifles, Scout Rifles, Handcannons, Sidearms,
>   Sub-machineguns

Power weapons are exclusively:

> Grenade Launchers, Rocket Launchers, Fusion Rifles, Sniper Rifles,
>   Swords, Shotguns, and Linear Fusion Rifles.

And as you have discovered, you can always press <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>LT</kbd>, whichever your appropriate keybinding is, to preview the weapon compared to your current equipped weapon in that slot.

Comment: Don't forget shotguns and linear fusion rifles.

Comment: Ha, good catch! I swear I had remembered shotguns. I omitted Linear Fusion Rifles because I believe there is only one in the game, which is the Veist one. I'll throw 'em in.

Comment: I honestly had to check and there's 3 (one is rare) but you're right that they aren't very different at all from normal fusion rifles, they even get infused together. Hopefully in the future we get more of them.

Answer (score 5):

I just figured a way to do that.

Generaly you can see this of course by the slot the weapon is available for.

In case of a quest reward or an engram, this might be hard to see before.
But you can still compare them to your current weapon by pressing Q while hoovering it. So you will see which of your 3 slots it is comparing to.

Comment: Pressing Q to compare isn't mentioned in the tool-tip at all! I thought they'd removed the ability to compare for the PC release. Good to know!

Comment: @Fluttershy Well sometimes there is a tooltip. Thats whereI know it from. sometimes it appears on the item when you are exchanging items in a slot. But I actually was suprised that it worked on the questreward, when trying it out in desperation.

Comment: @Fluttershy it shows up to the left of the weapon name in the popup box

Answer (score 5):

First it's best to know the difference between power weapons and the kinetic/energy weapons. Power weapons include: swords, rocket launchers, grenade launchers, sniper rifles, fusion rifles, linear fusion rifles, and shotguns. With the exception of one exotic grenade launcher being an energy weapon (Fighting Lion) these are always power weapons.

Now the difference between energy and kinetic. These weapons include: auto rifles, pulse rifles, scout rifles, hand-cannons, side-arms, and submachineguns. These weapons cannot be interchanged, meaning that even though there are mods that can change the element of a weapon (on both energy weapons and power weapons) they cannot be changed to kinetic and vise-versa.

You can quickly tell the difference between a kinetic and energy weapon in 2 ways. Energy weapons will obviously have an element, this will be shown with the purple, red, or blue icon of the respecting element type. Another more subtle way is the direction of the weapon in the icon. Kinetic weapons will always face from the grip in bottom right to the barrel in the top left, while energy (and power) weapons will face from bottom left to top right.

[image: Sunshot is an energy weapon and icon faces from left to right.]
Sunshot is an energy handcannon and its icon faces from left to right.

[image: Strum is a kinetic and faces right to left.]

Strum is a kinetic handcannon and faces right to left.

Comment: Wow - I've been playing Destiny for years and have plenty of (one might saw too many) hours in D2 and I never noticed that the guns face different directions. Guess I glossed over it.

Comment: In Destiny 1 I believe everything faced from left to right. I imagine this was probably a QOL addition in D2 so people could quickly differentiate a kinetic and energy as the icons would look almost identical for many legendaries.

Answer (score -2):

If the damage is elemental its Energy. If its normal its Kinetic.

Comment: Having a burn could also mean it's a power weapon

Comment: Also there are mods setting an elemental type.

Comment: Isn't this already said in the top answer?